# react-virtualized Infinite scroller issues with dynamic height

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am trying to mock Facebook feed like scroller in my application with [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized). I am following the reference from [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/tweets/blob/37d0139736346db16b9681d5b859a4e127964518/src/components/TweetList.js#L126-L132). I am trying to load two feeds at a time and after that `loadMoreRows` would be called to fetch the next two. I have hardcoded my feed size to 10 for testing purpose. It works well till 4th feed. Then I am not able to move after that smoothly. `rowRenderer` is triggering the numbers again and again which results in vibration effect on the screen. If I somehow move to the 10th feed and I scroll back, `rowRenderer` starts from 0 again. I assume it is due to varying height. Similar to the reference, I have used `CellMeasurerCache` and `CellMeasurer` to find the dynamic `height` and `width` and passing that to list.

```
class Scroller extends React.Component {
  _cache = new CellMeasurerCache({ defaultHeight: 100, fixedWidth: true });
  _resizeAllFlag = false; 
  _mostRecentWidth = 0;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      localCache: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this._loadData(0); 
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this._list);
    if(this._resizeAllFlag){
      this._resizeAllFlag = false;
      this._cache.clearAll();
      this._recomputeRowHeights();
    } else if(this.state.localCache !== prevState.localCache) {
      this._cache.clear(index, 0);
      this._recomputeRowHeights(index);
    }
  }
  ._loadData = (offset, callback) => {
    //Loads data from server and sets it in this.state.localCache
  }
  _recomputeRowHeights = (index) => {
    if (this._list) {
      console.log('Recomputing');
      this._list.recomputeRowHeights(index);
    }
  }
  _isRowLoaded = ({ index }) => {
    return !!this.state.localCache[index];
  }
  _loadMoreRows = ({ startIndex, stopIndex }) => {
    this._loadData(startIndex, (() => promiseResolver));
    let promiseResolver;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      promiseResolver = resolve;
    });
  }
  rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, parent }) => {
    const row = this.state.localCache[index];
    let content;
    if (row) {
      content = (<Feed data={row}/>);
    } else {
      content = (<CustomLoader />);
    }
    return (
      <CellMeasurer
        cache={this._cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        key={key}
        parent={parent}
        rowIndex={index}
        width={this._mostRecentWidth}
      > 
        {content} 
      </CellMeasurer>);
  }
  _setListRef = (ref) => {
    this._list = ref;
    this._registerList(ref);
  };
  _resizeAll = () => {
    this._resizeAllFlag = false;
    this._cache.clearAll();
    if (this._list) {
      this._list.recomputeRowHeights();
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { localCache } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="flex_grow">
        <InfiniteLoader
          isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
          loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
          rowCount={10}
        >
          {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) =>
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
              {({ width, height }) => {
                if (this._mostRecentWidth && this._mostRecentWidth !== width) {
                  this._resizeAllFlag = true;
                  setTimeout(this._resizeAll, 0);
                }
                this._mostRecentWidth = width;
                this._registerList = registerChild;
                return (
                  <List
                    deferredMeasurementCache={this._cache}
                    overscanRowCount={1}
                    ref={this._setListRef}
                    height={height}
                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                    rowCount={10}
                    rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
                    rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                    width={width}
                  />
                ) 
              }
              }
            </AutoSizer>}
        </InfiniteLoader>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

I might have deleted style props in content that is being passed. As per @Adrien's suggestion, I added it. My issues were not solved after adding style props.

```
rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, parent }) => {
  const row = this.state.localCache[index];
  let content;
  if (row) {
    content = (<Feed style={style} data={row}/>);
  } else {
    content = (<CustomLoader style={style}/>);
  }
  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={this._cache}
      columnIndex={0}
      key={key}
      parent={parent}
      rowIndex={index}
      width={this._mostRecentWidth}
    > 
      {content} 
    </CellMeasurer>);
}
```

And my Feed component

```
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { style } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="flex_grow" style={style}>
        {/* Feed related JSX */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My components seems to be overlapping. What could have been wrong?

**AnswerGist**:
https://gist.github.com/beb4/cc91f4e9b8982d172613cff248090769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `rowRenderer` style in your `content` component. According to [the docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#rowrenderer), this style is mandatory to position your row.

#### Corrected rowRenderer

```
rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, parent }) => {
    const row = this.state.localCache[index];
    let content;
    if (row) {
      content = (<Feed data={row} style={style} />); // <== HERE
    } else {
      content = (<CustomLoader style={style} />); // <== AND HERE
    }
    return (
      <CellMeasurer
        cache={this._cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        key={key}
        parent={parent}
        rowIndex={index}
        width={this._mostRecentWidth}
      > 
        {content} 
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I initially had style. Somehow, on editing I might have removed it. I added again as you suggested. Even with the `style` `props` added, I got the same issue.

Comment: @user2193672 Do you apply the `style` props on your root node inside your `Feed` component? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Yes. I passed `style` props to my `Feed` and `CustomLoader` , instead of passing to the `CellMeasurer` as you suggested. Have updated the question with it.

Comment: @user2193672 What I mean by applying `style` is not just passing the `style` props but handling it in the `Feed` component. Can you paste your `Feed` component? (only the render)

Comment: My bad! I applied the style in the `Feed` component, There is no problem with the rendering after properly appliying it. But the top and height set in the div is not correct. The components seems to overlap.

Comment: @user2193672, it may not be correlated but why is there a `disableHeight` prop on your `Autosizer`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151607/discussion-between-user2193672-and-adrien-lacroix).

Comment: I was having trouble in recomputing the row heights. I moved the implementation after loading new rows. It seems to work. Your suggestion on style was important to position to row. Accepting the answer. :)  Also I have updated the question with gist I have implemented.

Comment: If I add style the content is repeating